# Joining on a table but only match if it has at least one row based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I'm trying to find all users who have at least 1 transaction that has the StoreLocationID=123.

The basic query to get the count of users is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Users u
```

The transaction table looks like:

```
Transactions
- ID
- UserID
- Amount
- Date
- StoreLocationID
```

How can I find ALL users who have at least 1 transaction    where StoreLocationID=123.

I can join on the table, but I just need to know if there is at least 1 row with StoreLocationID=123.

Comment: Do you want the users information or just the count of users?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a correlated subquery with an `exists` condition:

```
select * 
from users u
where exists (
    select 1
    from transactions t
    where t.userID = u.userID
    and t.StoreLocationID = 123
)
```

This will give you all users that have at least one transaction on in store 123.

If you just want to count of such users, then:

```
select count(*) 
from users u
where exists (
    select 1
    from transactions t
    where t.userID = u.userID
    and t.StoreLocationID = 123
)
```

Or:

```
select count(distinct userID) from transactions where StoreLocationID = 123
```

Comment: should that be a join instead of a where clause?

Comment: @coolbreeze: we could `join`, but then we would need to aggregate, which may impact performance. `not exists` seems like a better option here, and also I find that it is easier to understand the intent of the query.